# MonoTouch .xcodeproj cannot be opened because the project file cannot be parsed

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to update my storyboard file and it doesn't open correctly due to the following error:

`".xcodeproj cannot be opened because the project file cannot be parsed.".`

I'm on the latest version of MonoTouch, so I don't think a previous bug can be attributed to this.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Cheers,

Davoc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [this bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3658), which has already been fixed (but is not in a released version yet).

[Comment 2](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3658#c2) has a possible workaround (but if it doesn't work you should file another bug, since it's not the same issue).